# Add class to existing classes using conditional [class]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using an ionic ion-icon

`<ion-icon name="checkmark" [class]="condition ? 'class1' : ''"></ion-icon>`

I'd like to add an extra class if the condition is true, but dont add the extra class if the condition is false.

Problem is, if the condition is false it removes all the pre-defined classes on the icon from Ionic Framework.

Comment: Before spamming solutions.... Are you using AngularJs or Angular? You entered both tags but the frameworks are completely different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to avoid binding to `class` directly.

Use either

```
[class.class1]="condition"
```

or

```
[ngClass]="condition ? 'class1' : ''"
```

With binding to `class` you explicitly bind the whole property value, instead of a single class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It's an "oldie", but this is how I solved my problem in case someone's looking an example of how to append classes conditionally to existing ones.

Basically I wanted to keep the `fa` bootstrap class applied, and only change the chevron from right to left if the side bar is collapsed or not. Also worked with a string literal and a terenary but get's messy, this way is much better (I think).

```
<button (click)="showHideSideClicked()">
    <span class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-chevron-left': isSideNavVisible, 'fa-chevron-right': !isSideNavVisible}"></span>
</button>
```

More about it @ [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description)